# detect extra attributes in frombody post payload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm looking for a way to detect extra attributes delivered on a WebAPI post payload that do not match the POCO I expect.  For example, here's an input object:

```
public class Input
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a controller method:

```
public void Post([FromBody]Input value)
```

If a client sends the following post payload:

```
{
    "Name" : "Foo",
    "Description" : "Bar"
}
```

This will trigger the Post method on my controller and Name will be populated.  I'd like to be aware that Description was sent but ignored, so I can either log that event server side or inform the client through a response header that they're sending extra data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is possible but you'd have to go without Model Binding and use reflection if you want a general solution:

Class:

```
public class Input
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Payload:

```
{
    "Name" : "Foo",
    "Description" : "Bar"
}
```

Controller Method:

```
public async void Post()
{
    //Read the content to a string   
    var content = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    //Get the Input object you wanted
    var input = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Input>(content);

    //Get a Dictionary containing all the content sent    
    var allContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(content);

    //Get the property names of the wanted object    
    var props = input.GetType().GetProperties().Select(a => a.Name);

    //See which properties are extra
    var extraContent = allContent.Keys.Except(props);
}
```

For the above example extraContent would be a list containing "Description". If you want the value just use the dictionary object.